# java Calender/formatter provides wrong date

Tags: java

Somehow I am being reported a issue, in which following code provides date in future.

The timezone used is GMT+01:00.
The *numberOfDays* is non negative integer.

The intention of this code is reduce the number of days from current date.

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yy",Locale.ENGLISH);
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -numberOfDays);
Date date = calendar.getTime();
String dateStr= formatter.format(date);
System.out.println("Date : "+dateStr);
```

I am not able to reproduce this on my machine.

Does the Locale affect the TimeZone?

I tried to correlate to [Why does a new SimpleDateFormat object contain calendar with the wrong year?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258441/why-does-a-new-simpledateformat-object-contain-calendar-with-the-wrong-year), and [Strange problem with timezone, calendar and SimpleDateFormat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092340/strange-problem-with-timezone-calendar-and-simpledateformat) but in vain.

Please help me understand and rectify this issue.

Comment: Works for me actually (Prints `Date : 25 Feb 11` for me; I'm on GMT). Which timezone is your system on?

Comment: Just to clarify: where you able to reproduce the problem locally? Or did you just get an unverified report?

Comment: Maybe is should be DAY_OF_YEAR instead of DAY_OF_MONTH ?

Comment: @adarshr: Works for me too, I have changed my system timezone to GMT+1.00                                                              @Martin: Thanks, but I do not have to authority to change the implementation unless I prove the need for it.                 @Joachim Sauer: I am still not able to reproduce the problem

Answer (score 2):

Well, two possibilities I can think of off the top of my head:

- The system date on the client machine is incorrect, so the calendar *starts* with a date in the future
- If `numberOfDays` is negative, it will obviously push the date into the future

The `Locale` isn't directly related to the time zone - they're independent, although obviously a machine with a French locale is *likely* to be in a French time zone etc.

Personally I would avoid using Date/Calendar entirely and use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) as a *much* nicer date and time API, but that wouldn't help with either of the ideas I gave above...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. From what is being told, the date is correctly set and the numberOfDays is non negative integer. I can't really change the implementation without providing the cause for the bug, hence cannot use Joda Time.

Comment: @Nilesh: Can you print out the date *before* the call to `add` (and the value of `numberOfDays`) for diagnostic purposes? What's your relationship like with the person having the problem?

Comment: I could see the correct date on my local machines before `add`; also the numberOfDays is not negative , the client who has this problem is far than reachable, I do not have any information/access to the place where this is occurring.

Comment: @Nilesh: Well that's where you need to get the information, I'm afraid. I'm not surprised that numberOfDays is positive and the date is correct on the machine where you *can't* reproduce the problem :)